# Correspondence between monomer-dimer heaps and words in 2 alphabets

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

For background and some illustrative pictures, refer to this preprint by A M Grasia and G Ganzberger: [Fibonacci polynomials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.10213.pdf). For the present purpose, it suffices to read into pages 4 and 5.

The part that interested me comes from the map between monomer-dimer heaps and 2-alphabet (finite) words, where
a monomer of ground coordinate $i$ corresponds to $m_i$ and a dimer projecting to the interval $[i-1,i]$ corresponds to $d_i$. For examples, look into the [above paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.10213.pdf).

It becomes clear that several words $w$ might be associated to a given a monomer-dimer heap.

> **QUESTION.** Is it possible to determine the number of words corresponding to a given heap? More modestly, is there an algorithm to compute such number?